# B2C Custom policy asking for SignIn again with profile edit after an error in profile edit step

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm working with custom policies, i have a profile edit policy, in which i have an OTP validation step (a self asserted step). I have set the retry limit of this step to 10. If the profile edit happens without any error, everything is fine. But if some error occurs, say i have entering an invalid OTP for 10 times then the self asserted steps retry will get exceeded and will throw an error. I'm handling that in my application and if i try to re launch the profile edit policy again it will ask for login. But the normal flow is not asking for signin (if no error happened during profile edit previously), also `Request.IsAuthenticated` in my ASP.NET application is **true**. Any idea